# REST POST controller saying: Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: json, rest, testing, post

I'm doing an integration test against a REST controller POST handler. Well, I'm trying to.

It gives me the HttpMessageNotReadableException exception: Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("admin")
public class AdminController {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminController.class);

    private static final String TEMPLATE = "Hello, %s!";

    @Autowired 
    private AdminService adminService;

    @Autowired
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "crud", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Admin> add(@RequestBody Admin admin, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
        AdminCreatedEvent adminCreatedEvent = adminService.add(new CreateAdminEvent(admin.toEventAdmin()));
        Admin createdAdmin = Admin.fromEventAdmin(adminCreatedEvent.getEventAdmin());
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        responseHeaders.setLocation(builder.path("/admin/{id}").buildAndExpand(adminCreatedEvent.getAdminId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Admin>(createdAdmin, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleException(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

The base test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration( classes = { ApplicationConfiguration.class, WebSecurityConfig.class, WebConfiguration.class, WebTestConfiguration.class })
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    protected MockHttpSession session;

    protected MockHttpServletRequest request;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }

}
```

The integration test:

```
@Test
public void testAdd() throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = Common.createAuthenticationHeaders("stephane" + ":" + "mypassword");
    this.mockMvc.perform(
        post("/admin/crud").headers(httpHeaders)
        .param("firstname", "Stephane")
        .param("lastname", "Eybert")
        .param("login", "stephane")
        .param("password", "toto")
    ).andDo(print())
    .andExpect(
        status().isOk()
    ).andReturn();
}
```

What the console log has to say:

```
2013-11-04 19:31:23,168 DEBUG  [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@158ddda0: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@158ddda0: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@552e813c: Username: stephane; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'
2013-11-04 19:31:23,168 DEBUG  [RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor] Written [Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 1]] as "application/json;charset=utf-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@10d328]
2013-11-04 19:31:23,169 DEBUG  [TestDispatcherServlet] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name '': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2013-11-04 19:31:23,169 DEBUG  [TestDispatcherServlet] Successfully completed request
2013-11-04 19:31:23,169 DEBUG  [ExceptionTranslationFilter] Chain processed normally
2013-11-04 19:31:23,169 DEBUG  [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /admin/crud
          Parameters = {firstname=[Stephane], lastname=[Eybert], login=[stephane], password=[toto]}
             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json], Authorization=[Basic c3RlcGhhbmU6bXlwYXNzd29yZA==]}

             Handler:
                Type = com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController
              Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.domain.Admin> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.add(com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.domain.Admin,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:
MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 200
       Error message = null
             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=utf-8], Content-Length=[254]}
        Content type = application/json;charset=utf-8
                Body = Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 1]
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
2013-11-04 19:31:23,177 DEBUG  [TransactionalTestExecutionListener] No method-level @Rollback override: using default rollback [true] for test context [TestContext@ce4625 testClass = AdminControllerTest, testInstance = com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.AdminControllerTest@1b62fcd, testMethod = testAdd@AdminControllerTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@9be79a testClass = AdminControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.config.ApplicationConfiguration, class com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.config.WebSecurityConfig, class com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.config.WebConfiguration, class com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.config.WebTestConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the .param() methods in favor of the .content() one:

```
        post("/admin/crud").headers(httpHeaders)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content("{ \"firstname\" : \"" + admin0.getFirstname() + "\", \"lastname\" : \"" + admin0.getLastname() + "\", \"email\" : \"" + admin0.getEmail() + "\", \"login\" : \"" + admin0.getLogin() + "\", \"password\" : \"" + admin0.getPassword() + "\", \"passwordSalt\" : \"" + admin0.getPasswordSalt() + "\" }")
    ).andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isCreated())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname").value(admin0.getFirstname()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastname").value(admin0.getLastname()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email").value(admin0.getEmail()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.login").value(admin0.getLogin()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.password").value(admin0.getPassword()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.passwordSalt").value(admin0.getPasswordSalt()))
    .andReturn();
```

And it now works as expected.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion the problem is with content format. Your endpoint expect that data will be sent as *application/json* but in test you send it as *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* (it doesn't matter that you set proper content type header in request). Try to send admin object in json format (as a body of a request):

```
{
 "firstname" : "Stephane",
 "lastname" : "Eybert",
 "login" : "stephane",
 "password" : "toto"
}
```

BTW the `/admin/crud` does not fallow REST resource addressing rules, you should change it to `/admin`. The crud (CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE) will map to HTTP methods (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE)

Comment: Thanks for the addressing rule. Indeed I didn't want to use this "crud" name but wondered what to have. The thing is my controller has a mapping as "admin" at the class level: @RequestMapping("/admin") public class AdminController which left me puzzled as to what mapping I should have at the method level:     @RequestMapping(value = "/crud", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8") @ResponseBody public ResponseEntity<Admin> add(...)

Comment: I think that you can use `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")` at method level. It will bind the method to `/admin`

Comment: Yes indeed, it works fine without the value attribute, thanks !