# SRVE0014E: uncaught service exception

Tags: jersey, websphere

I am getting below exception on one of our development environment. But it is working fine on another environment. unable to catch the trick. Can somebody help on this.

```
    SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause Jersey Spring Web 
    Application:  `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.EOFException: 
    No content to map to Object due to end of input `
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775704/rest-post-controller-saying-could-not-read-json-no-content-to-map-due-to-end-o

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925058/no-content-to-map-due-to-end-of-input-jackson-parser

Answer (score 0):

SRVE0014E appears to be application error. I would recommend checking the application log during the time of the exception thrown from the WebSphere exception. Additionally,  investigate the functionality and behavior of Jersey Spring Web Application.