# Why is my Java app getting killed?

Tags: java, exception

I could be wrong about which line is causing the problem, but the error changes everytime I change this if() statement:

```
try {
     while(true) {
        String LRU = hashOperation();
        System.out.println("In worker thread, this should be valid JSON: " + LRU);
        if (jsonValidator.isStringValidJSON(LRU) && !LRU.isEmpty()) {
              HashMap<String,String> messageMap = jsonGenerator.readJSON(LRU);
```

So I assume the problem is with this if() statement. If I write it like this:

```
if (jsonValidator.isStringValidJSON(LRU)) {
```

Then the app starts up and I get this exception:

```
In worker thread, this should be valid JSON: 
Exception in worker thread in Main::main: No content to map to Object due to end of input
```

but if I write it like this:

```
if (jsonValidator.isStringValidJSON(LRU) && !LRU.isEmpty()) {
```

Then the app starts up, but then almost instantly dies:

```
/usr/bin/java -cp /home/jenkins/run-nlp/SSAM.jar com.sofar.SSAM.Main
Starting NLP app 2015/08/30 21:42:28

Loading classifier from dependencies/english.all.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Killed
```

The basic idea here is that the app starts up and then spins up some background threads that poll endlessly on Redis, looking for input (the input comes from another app, that publishes data to a channel on Redis).

When I see "Killed" I assume that an Exception went uncaught, but I have this whole Thread::run() wrapped in a try/catch that ends with:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception in worker thread in Main::main: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

You can see that this is the Exception message that I get if I do this:

```
if (jsonValidator.isStringValidJSON(LRU)) {
```

Although it is possible the error is elsewhere, and I think it is odd that an empty string would be valid JSON, I thought I would screen out that possibility with:

```
if (jsonValidator.isStringValidJSON(LRU) && !LRU.isEmpty()) {
```

Why would this one change cause my app to be Killed?

UPDATE:

I refactored the app to this:

```
static void processMessage(ssamBrain ssamBrain, Jedis jedis, HashMap<String, String> responseMap, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, JSONValidator jsonValidator, String LRU) {
try {
        if (!LRU.isEmpty()) {
            HashMap<String,String> messageMap = jsonGenerator.readJSON(LRU);
            Transformer transformer = new Transformer();
```

Again, the line that causes the problem seems to be:

```
        if (!LRU.isEmpty()) {
```

If I don't have that if() statement, then the code gets:

```
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
```

on the next line, since an empty string is not valid JSON.

But when I add this:

```
        if (!LRU.isEmpty()) {
```

Then my app dies on startup.

Maybe autoboxing is the problem? Or the absence of it? Assume for now:

LRU = "";

I assume I can call methods on it, but maybe not? And why wouldn't I get an Exception?

It's possible the problem is elsewhere, but that if() statement seems to be the main thing that causes the problem to surface.

UPDATE

UPDATE

The app sometimes survives for a few minutes, but other times it dies after a few seconds. So I guess I need to ask:

1.) when a Java app says "Killed" in the terminal, does that always mean that an Exception went uncaught?

2.) what might cause such variable behavior?

Comment: Instead of printing `e.getMessage()`, use simply `e.printStackTrace();` - this will give you plenty more info to work with.

Comment: This may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775704/rest-post-controller-saying-could-not-read-json-no-content-to-map-due-to-end-o

Comment: Luis Sieira, I would be happy if I could get an Exception. Right now I just get "Killed" after the app starts up.

Comment: Oh hell, it just started up and ran for several minutes without a problem. So perhaps the problem with the app is something else. This app is just awful. It was written by a co-worker and now I have to re-write it.

Comment: And the app just died again on startup. So I guess the real question is, what would cause the app to intermittently die? Sometimes it lasts minutes, sometimes it lasts seconds.

Answer (score 0):

How to works if operator:

```
if (CONDITION_1 && CONDITION_2){
 doSomething();
}
```

1. checks CONDITION_1 - if it is true:
2. checks CONDITION_2 - if it is true:
3. runs doSometring().

If CONDITION_1 is false or throws an exception, CONDITION_2 never checks.

1. Please, show the exception stackTrace.
2. Change:

   ```
   if (jsonValidator.isStringValidJSON(LRU) && !LRU.isEmpty())
   ```

to:

```
    if (!LRU.isEmpty() && jsonValidator.isStringValidJSON(LRU))
```

So, you first check if LRU is empty and if it is not - you run validation.

Comment: Well, I tried to refactor to smaller methods, and now the app is "Killed" on startup so I can not get any Exceptions or stack traces. If I can get them, I'll post them.

Comment: Seems like the empty string is passing the validJson test, but I'll try it.