# Rest template delete not working

Tags: spring-mvc, resttemplate, http-method

I tried invoking delete operation via RestTemplate's delete method but it's not working.
My Rest controller code for delete

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
 @ResponseBody
  public DeleteResponse deleteRecords(
  @RequestBody final DeleteRequest DeleteRequest) {

    DeleteResponse response=new DeleteResponse();
    //invoke respective services to do delete operations
    response.setStatus("success");
    response.setMessage("all records deleted successfully");
    return response;

  }

  Class DeleteRequest{
    @JsonProperty(value="userId")
    String userId;
    @JsonProperty(value="records")
    List<Record>  records;
  }
  class Record{
    @JsonProperty(value="key1")
        String key1;
    @JsonProperty(value="key2")
        String key2;
    @JsonProperty(value="key3")
        String key3;
  }
```

//Client invocation

```
 public void deleteRecords(String url,DeleteRequest deleteRequest){
    resttemplate.delete(url, deleteRequest);
}
```

I am invoking **put** in similar way its working fine.
for delete i get below exception
Exception occured : Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input.

To check whether there is a problem in the way I am passing the json values I created a class extending RestTemplate and added a method performActionForObject

```
public class MyRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {

    public <T> T performActionForObject(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType,HttpMethod method) throws RestClientException {
        RequestCallback requestCallback = httpEntityCallback(request, responseType);
        HttpMessageConverterExtractor<T> responseExtractor =
                new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<T>(responseType, getMessageConverters());
        return execute(url, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
    }

}
```

then invoked delete operation as below

```
DeleteResponse response= resttemplate.performActionForObject(url, deleteRequest, DeleteResponse.class, HttpMethod.DELETE);
```

It didn't work i got the same exception
so i changed delete to post in both controller and rest client it worked 
perfectly.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
     @ResponseBody
      public DeleteResponse deleteRecords(
      @RequestBody final DeleteRequest DeleteRequest) {

DeleteResponse response= resttemplate.performActionForObject(url, deleteRequest, DeleteResponse.class, HttpMethod.POST);
```

**Not sure why it's not working when i use delete**

Comment: Please define "not working", any stacktrace?

Comment: I get  Exception occured : Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775704/rest-post-controller-saying-could-not-read-json-no-content-to-map-due-to-end-o maybe